# Unable to get current timestamp in PDT timezone

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get the current timestamp and then its hour by doing the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
curr = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_date = curr.split(':')[0]+':00:00'
```

I'm getting the output for `end_date` as follows: `2018-11-10 10:00:00`. But this is currently in `UTC` time. How do I get it in `PDT` time?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by importing the `pytz` module. Also, you can just generate the date format you need from the datetime object. So based on your code snippet, PDT time can be obtained like this.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

curr = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
full_date = curr.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
hour_date = curr.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import pyzt module to get the time for the time zone that you want. Check this [documentation](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/)

Comment: And try to avoid adding the + ':00:00' at the end because sometimes you may forget it and cause some problems.